# copy the same file content into multiple files

Tags: bash, xargs, cp

Let's say I have text file called template.txt. template.txt contains the text "hello world."

I also have 10 other files named, message1, message2, message3, ect.

How can I copy the contents of template_message into message1, message2, message3, ect?

So far I've tried:

```
cp --copy-contentes template.txt *

cp --copy-contentes template.txt | xargs ls
```

Comment: `for i in message{1..10}; do cp template.txt $i; done`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a loop:

```
for file in message*
do
    cp template.txt "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

yet another way of doing this

```
ls message* | xargs -n1  cp template.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! CLI one liner are best than loops

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop and append the index to the end of your destination file.

```
for i in {1..10};
do
    cp template.txt "message$i"
done
```

Comment: no need to use `seq` if the range is known beforehand, use `{1..10}`

Comment: You're right, and when you're right you're right. So you're right.